# jmeter extract the xpath from a soap responce

Tags: xml, soap, xpath, jmeter

Please help me to find out the XPATH from the following xml. I need to find the value based on the key.

For example if I am using "key2", i need to get the value 20.

I tried the following XPATH but it is not giving the expected result in JMeter

```
//ns1:dataResponse/ns1:return/ns2:entries/ns2:Entry[ns2:key='key2']/ns2:value
```

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""><soap:Body>
  <ns1:dataResponse xmlns:ns1="">
     <ns1:return xsi:type="ns2:StatementData" xmlns:ns2="" xmlns:xsi="">
        <ns2:entries>
           <ns2:Entry xsi:type="ns2:Entry">
              <ns2:dataList xsi:nil="true"/>
              <ns2:key>key1</ns2:key>
              <ns2:value xsi:type="xsd:double" xmlns:xsd="">10</ns2:value>
           </ns2:Entry>
           <ns2:Entry xsi:type="ns2:Entry">
              <ns2:dataList xsi:nil="true"/>
              <ns2:key>key2</ns2:key>
              <ns2:value xsi:type="xsd:double" xmlns:xsd="">20</ns2:value>
           </ns2:Entry>
           <ns2:Entry xsi:type="ns2:Entry">
              <ns2:dataList xsi:nil="true"/>
              <ns2:key>key3</ns2:key>
              <ns2:value xsi:type="xsd:double" xmlns:xsd="">30</ns2:value>
           </ns2:Entry>
     </ns1:return>
  </ns1:dataResponse>
```

Comment: Why are the namespace URIs empty? Show the _actual_ namespace declarations.

Comment: because of some security reasons, i have removed the same from this question.

Comment: Security reasons that keep you from posting publicly availabe namespace URIs? Anyway, what do you mean by "not giving expected result"? What _do_ you get back?

Comment: i am using xpath extractor in jmeter and assiging the value to a user defined variable. but it is always taking the default value. http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ is the namespace

Comment: Posted XML fragment is not well formed. There is no closing `<ns2:entries>` for instance. Please update question with proper XML. Seconding  what @MathiasMüller said, Please post namespace declarations.